# How to get iCloud email address from Apple ID?

Tags: icloud

How can I detect icloud email address of the user if he provided Apple ID and Password?

Manoj

Comment: I think this can be fetched from https://setup.icloud.com/setup/get_account_settings. Don't know this is the right method or not.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps you can follow to get the iCloud email from your Apple ID.

● Firstly, go to the iCloud website and sign in with your account.

● After that, select the Create Email Address option.

● Then, create an account by following the instructions you see on the screen.

● Also, if an inbox appears instead of the Create Email address option, then your account has already been created.